# How to store and retrieve compound key values with Redis

Tags: redis

I would like to store serialized objects in Redis from a database table with a compound primary key of two values. The objects might look like the following in code:

```
Public Class Contact
    Public Property Instance_Id() As Long
    Public Property Contact_Id() As Long
    Public Property First_Name() As String
    Public Property Last_Name() As String
End Class
```

The Instance_Id is shared amongst a group of contacts, and the Contact_Id value is unique to each contact.

What is the fastest and most memory efficient way to store these objects in Redis where I can retrieve all the Contacts with a specific Instance_Id, or just the one Contact with a specific Contact_Id ?

Comment: Which redis version? 2.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would build a hash for each contact of the form (contact_id => Contact class data), which can be queried directly by the key (contact_id) to solve your specific lookup case.  Then, add  a (sorted, if you care about ordering) set of (instance_id => [contact_id1, contact_id2, ... , contact_idN]).  To look up by instance_id, you would fetch contact_ids from the index set in one query, then for each id you got back, do a specific lookup for each of those ids.

From an RDBMS viewpoint, this sounds crazy, I realize, because you're used to thinking of a query as an expensive operation.  Redis commands are designed to be extremely fast, so sending a large batch of commands to do what would be one query in an RDBMS is reasonably efficient.